# MS Azure DB: cannot find data type XML & Incorrect syntax near ' Identity'

Tags: sql-server, xml, azure, sql-server-2016

I was trying to change the data type into XML in order to split one column into multiple columns. However, when I ran the syntax below, an error: **cannot find data type XML** was showed. I searched some of the answers online. It seems Azure is supported for XML. Is there a way to solve it?

```
cast('<m>'+replace(Employee_Name,@delimiter,'</m><m>')+'</m>' as XML)
```

Besides, I found that **IDENTITY(1,1)** is not supported either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL-Server 2016 there is native support for this: [`STRING_SPLIT()`-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx). But - according to the linked doumentation - this seems not to be offered for *Azure Data Warehouse*...

The string splitting via XML needs the XML-DataType, since you will need `.nodes()` and `.value()` to retrieve the values. According to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx) this is supported with *Azure Database*, don't know of restriction with the *Data Warehouse* version...

There are many examples for string splitting functions using loops or recursive CTEs. [This article](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) compares some of them...

Comment: Yup. Unfortunately, it is doable to use **String_Split()** under Azure DB, but not for warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to run the query casting to XML while logged into a Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse. Azure SQL Data Warehouse does not support the XML datatype. You can confirm your version with the following sql:

select @@version

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-data-types

Comment: Mine is MS SQL Azure Data Warehouse 2016. Anyway, do you know the solution to split one column into multiple columns without using XML, or can we install XML package etc.?

Comment: Can you use varchar instead of xml?


`cast('<m>'+replace(Employee_Name,@delimiter,'</m><m>')+'</m>' as varchar)`

Comment: @AndrewW `VARCHAR` would not help in this case... This is a *trick* to split strings by replacing a delimiter with XML-tags. `this,is,delimited` transforms to `<m>this</m><m>is</m><m>delimited</m>`. With XML-methods `.nodes()` and `.value()` you can read this part by part...